# Dynamically define association callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

We have some ActiveRecord:

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  include Auditable
end

module Auditable

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def notify_keywords_change
    # Some logic goes here
  end
end
```

How can I set #notify_content_change as after_add and after_remove callbacks for HABTM association :tags? I need to implement this inside Auditable module to make it reusable.

Actually, I'm working on a concern module, that should track model's association changes. As there no "Dirty" functionality for collection associations (HABTM and has_many), I found solution to track such changes with callbacks - https://anti-pattern.com/dirty-associations-with-activerecord

Now I need make Auditable concern somehow respond to changes in association collection. And finally record models revision, including different associations.

I need some simplified version of auditable gem, but with association support (not attributes only).

Comment: Have a look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations

Comment: I've got reflection with Node.reflect_on_association(:tags) #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasAndBelongsToManyReflection:***> - but I can't find out a method for defining callbacks.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for a worker than a model callback. But I'm still not clear on what you're actually trying to do.  Can you please clarify ?  Also wrap code in backtics in comments. See help

Comment: I've updated my initial question with some details and final goal.